# use an array of node pointers to point to a child of a node

Tags: c++, pointers, nodes

I need a node to point to multiple children (I don't know how many of which I have at compile time).
for the time being I only need the father node to point to at least one child.
but it's pointing to '0', what have I missed?
here is my code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string tokens[10];

typedef struct node
{
    char* value;
    node* children[10]={NULL};
}node;

void connect(node* father,node* child)
{
   // child = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node*));
    if(father->children[0]!=NULL)
        father->children[0]=child;
        cout<<father->children[0]<<endl;
}

int main()
{

node* father_ = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node*));
node* child_ = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node*));
cout<<"before\n";
connect(father_,child_);
cout<<"after\n";

father_->children[0]->value="a";
cout<<child_->value;

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: You meant to use `sizeof(node)` not `sizeof(node*)`.

Comment: I wanted to write an answer to your question but it would be only quoting chapters from any C++ book. Try searching for dynamic memory allocation in C++; constructors, destructors and RAII; linked list and data structures.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` <- what

Comment: @underscore_d go to the link provided by πάντα ῥεῖ  to check out what that header does, however I only used it because this is a quick prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(father->children[0]!=NULL)
    father->children[0]=child;
```

You only instantiate a father-child relation if the father already has a non-null first child. Change `!=` into `==` (or even drop that `!=NULL` part, but then negate the condition).

Answer (score 2):

What's the obsession with pointers? Here a more c++ version.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct node
{
    std::string value;
    std::vector<node*> children;
};

void connect(node* father,node* child)
{
    father->children.push_back(child);
}

int main()
{
    auto father = std::make_unique<node>();
    auto child = std::make_unique<node>();

    connect( father.get(), child.get());

    father->children[0]->value="a";

    std::cout << child->value;
}
```

**[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1104b26acb0e0f89)**

Note:

- avoid `using naespace std`
- don't use `malloc` and `free`
- you don't need to typedef struct in c++
- use containers such as string and vector
- avoid c style arrays
- don't use raw pointers for ownership

Comment: your code simply works, and I like the pure C++ approach you provided, pretty neat.

Comment: While I could have fixed your issue, I though it better to provide a solution that avoids the problem.

Comment: I appreciate your help, truly. while I couldn't completely steer away from pointers in this particular project, I found it useful to use vectors to avoid pointing to pointers. however using c++14 methods and variables is not applicable in my situation.